# Fetching all the Project Name for a Project Cumulative Flow Chart in Rally

Tags: highcharts, rally, code-rally

I am generating a Project Cumulative Flow Chart, which is based on the Project name that I fetch using a "find," however I can't get it working.

Here is the Problem:
1) The "Find" in my code is just fetching one kind of project name, "FE," however, I have a lot of other Project name such as FE, BE, VisualRF, etc. I am not sure what's going on

2) I return this to "storeConfig" inside the chart and then I want try to give "Name" to the "stateFieldName." This is not working! I don't see any graph at all.

Here is the code.

```
    _chart2: function() {
    var projectName = this.getContext().getProject()._refObjectName;
    console.log("========");
    console.log(projectName);   <<<<<<<<<< This always prints one name'FE' (My project name are FE, BE, etc)
    this.chart = {
            xtype: 'rallychart',
            storeType: 'Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore',
            storeConfig: this._getStoreForChart2(),
            calculatorType: 'Rally.example.CFDCalculator',
            calculatorConfig: {
              stateFieldName: this.getContext().getProject()._refObjectName, <<<<< I think usage is not fetching name of all projects 
              stateFieldValues: ['FE','BE','VisualRF']                  
            },
            width: 1000,
            height: 600,
            chartConfig: this._getChart2Config()
        };
    this.chartContainer.add(this.chart);
},


_getStoreForChart2: function() {        
    var obj1 = {
        find: {
            _TypeHierarchy: { '$in' : [ 'Defect' ] },
            Children: null,
            _ProjectHierarchy: this.getContext().getProject().ObjectID,
            _ValidFrom: {'$gt': Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString(Rally.util.DateTime.add(new Date(), 'day', -30)) },
            State: "Open",
        },
        fetch: ['Severity','Project','ObjectID','FormattedID'],
        hydrate: ['Severity','Project','ObjectID','FormattedID'],
        sort: {
            _ValidFrom: 1
        },
        context: this.getContext().getDataContext(),
        limit: Infinity,
        val: this.Name,
    };
    return obj1;
},
```

Though this should not matter but here is the code for the high chart function I am calling above

```
  _getChart2Config: function() {
    console.log("starting chart config");
    return {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart2'
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            tickInterval: 20,
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: [
            {
                title: {
                    text: 'Count'
                }
            }
        ],
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            area: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        }
    };
},
```

Down below you can see 'FE' getting printed:
[image: You can see FE bring printed, but my 'Find' returns a lot results. I have to pass them to the stateFieldName so that all the values be used to draw the Project Cumulative Flow Chart]

Thanks a lot!
Kay

Comment: @kylemorse can you please help me in this. Thanks!

Comment: Please run the console (developer tools in the Chrome) and observe what kind of errors do you receive.

Comment: @sebastian I am not receiving any errors. What you see on the top is the console screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

stateFieldName is the field which is used to calculate the CFD- usually ScheduleState or a custom dropdown field like KanbanState that captures your process.  The stateFieldValues should be the values of that field (Defined, In-Progress, Accepted, Completed, etc.)  This doesn't deal with projects at all.  Definitely remember to include that field in your hydrate and fetch as well.

Comment: then how do I create charts based on the values of project names, in my above code, if following code won't work?                calculatorConfig: {
              stateFieldName: this.getContext().getProject()._refObjectName, <<<<< I think usage is not fetching name of all projects 
              stateFieldValues: ['FE','BE','VisualRF']                  
            },

Comment: the cumulative flow chart is not really designed to show multiple projects individually in the same chart.  you can roll them all up together and show them in the same chart though.  i guess i don't totally understand what chart you're trying to make...

Comment: I am trying to see all the defects by the Project (such as FE, BE, etc)  in some kind of chart. If not cumulative flow then what chart from rally is good for this purpose? Thanks Kay